# Ordering numbers in SharePoint using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a lot of documents given an [Issue Number] which goes in such fashion:

> 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.3 ..... 1.1.9, 1.1.10

When ordering by the Issue Number then the 1.1.10 is ordered underneath 1.1.1 because this is how the numeric numbers work in computer's world.

In such a case, either I need to rename the issue number (which is not allowed) or I need to add another Single Line Field naming [orderBy] and use it as

> 1.1.01, 1.1.02.... 1.1.09, 1.1.10, 1.1.11

Or, there may be a JavaScript out there which can be used.
Any advise?

Comment: Do you need JavaScript code to Order by Issue Number ? Assume Issue Number is List Item Number field over here.

Comment: Hi @SukumarMS , the [IssueNumber] is a Text Field as the Numeric field only allows you to type in certain format :/ at least that is what I got the impression from .... though, I tried now to change from text to numeric , the SP won't allow me to :(

Comment: Why not create three numeric (calculated) fields in order to sort by the semantic version and store major, minor and patch version as numbers

Comment: Hey @SteveT I am not sure how to achieve that? maybe you can reply to the topic and add some screenshots, detailing this ... thanks